# What is the RAREST thing to spawn in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

These are things like, Spider Jockeys and Baby Zombies riding regular zombies and stuff like that. But, I want to know the most rarest thing to spawn in Minecraft naturally.

Answer (score 2):

Rays Works has an excellent series about rare mobs. Here is his latest video on the new rarest mob:

It happens to be a strider riding a strider, riding a strider, etc. with a final baby zombie piglin on top, with a Jack-O-Lantern head.

Comment: This was [a since-fixed bug](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-176028)

Comment: Cool. Thanks for providing this. After this bug fix, I assume it has gone back to it's old rarest mob, skeleton horse with a skeleton riding it, with a Jack-O-lantern head, and diamond horse armor, with diamond armor on the skeleton. Or something like that. The series goes over it all